# Pandas date range query gives "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am receiving the following error and I don't know how to rectify it:

> TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I found a couple of other StackOverflow posts with similar but they didn't offer me much help.

I have a very vanilla csv, with a lot of duplication (by design). The start and end date shift over 100's of rows.

```
Start,End,Members,Day
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
2009-07-04,2010-07-03,96,0
```

And a few lines of code:

```
df_contracts = read_csv("_raw_contracts.csv")
df_contracts['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df_contracts['Start'])
df_contracts['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df_contracts['End'])
anchor = pd.Timestamp('2010-01-01T12')
df = df_contracts.loc(df_contracts['Start'] < anchor) & (df_contracts['End'] > anchor)
```

but I can't figure out why I am getting the type error?

Comment: You have to use square brackets: `df_contracts.loc[(df_contracts['Start'] < anchor) & (df_contracts['End'] > anchor)]` or without `loc`: `df_contracts[(df_contracts['Start'] < anchor) & (df_contracts['End'] > anchor)]`

Comment: Thanks, loc and square brackets worked. Without loc still threw a (different) error. If you want to add that as an answer I'll accept it.